# Get tabbarcontroller from another view on my storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

In my Delegate i am trying to select my `TabBarController` so that i can style it with a different background. However the problem is that my `TabBarController` is not located on the rootView..

My current code:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
```

In my interface builder i have my `TabBarController` setup with a Segue name: mainView (This is where the `TabBarController` is located).

How could i select my `TabBarController`?

Comment: in which part of the code do you want to select your tabBarController? In a UIViewController that is inside the TabBar, APPDelegate,... ?

Comment: Yea on my first line i want to replace `self.window.rootViewController;` with my TabBarController so that i can manipulate it

Comment: Yea, but I want to know in what ViewController/method you are calling the piece of code that you just posted

Comment: Ah sorry, it is in my AppDelegate.m

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, you have to know in your view hierarchy where is your TabBarController. If it's not your root controller, Locate the UIViewController that are calling the TabBarController, and get it's reference by segue or something like it.

What might work for you, it's accessing the `tabBarController` property in the `viewDidLoad` of the first child UIViewController in a tab inside your tabViewController. **All** child ViewControllers of the tabBarController have this property.

For example, assuming first UIViewController displayed in the tabBar is MyViewController, perform something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
   UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
   UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1]; 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to get it from ONE OF the VIEWS

```
//if Custom class
TabBarController *tabBar = (TabBarController *) self.tabBarController;

//if Custom class with Navigation Controller
TabBarController *tabBar = (TabBarController *) self.navigationController.tabBarController;

//if Not Subclassed
UITabBarController *tabBar = (UITabBarController *) self.tabBarController;

//if Not Subclassed with Navigation Controller
UITabBarController *tabBar = (UITabBarController *) self.navigationController.tabBarController;
```