# How to pass data from one tabbar to another in swift?

Tags: ios, swift2, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I want to pass data from one tabBar controller to another,

I am switching tabBar using    `tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0`

I tried many option but unable to pass data to another tab, is there any simple solution like we pass data using navigation controller?

Comment: You can always use NSNotificationCenter to send data to anywhere. Did you consider using it?

Comment: Yes, notification and nsuserdefault is way, but think there should be another way to do that

Comment: Btw, how do you pass data with navigation controller?

Answer (score 0):

Tabs are usually some custom UIViewControllers. From these view controllers (tabs) you can also get access to the UITabBarController with something like:

```
if let mainController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window??.rootViewController as? YourMainTabBarControllerClass {
    mainController.someVariable = 123
}
```

Here you have to be careful, because the tab bar controller may not be the rootViewController, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970004/get-tabbarcontroller-from-another-view-on-my-storyboard) for more details.

In order to store some properties in the UITabBarController you have to implement your own class by extending UITabBarController and then set the custom class in the StoryBoard. The class will then look like:

```
class YourMainTabBarControllerClass: UITabBarController {

    // some custom variables here...
    var someVariable = 0

    ...

}
```